# What's the difference between "along with", "coupled with", "combined with"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, word-difference, phrase-choice

> the killing cold temperature and the cutting wind combined with our clammy feet

sounds inappropriate.

Should we use:

> 1. the killing cold temperature, the cutting wind, and our clammy feet
> 2. the killing cold temperature and the cutting wind (coupled/along with) our clammy feet

For reference:
We brought a beach tent, set it up on a hard ground that seemed impenetrable. Without a ground sheet or even an earth pad, the killing cold temperature and the cutting wind combined with our clammy feet made us feel like we won’t survive the night.

Comment: You have a problem here with _clammy feet._ The other conditions sound threatening enough, but nobody _in any language_ ever failed to survive the night due to _clammy feet!_ The idea and both phrases are, frankly, hilarious in that context, and I don't think you're trying for humor here. Or are you?

Comment: @P.E I disagree. It's common to utter something like *If I get bitten by another mosquito, I'm going to die.* Such would likely be a typical example of hyperbole, not neccessarily expressive of humor. Besides, if the combined effect of those factors were sufficiently intense, a speaker could be quite reasonably concerned  about survival.

Comment: To this reader, at leaat, it sounds unintentionally humorous.

Comment: @P.E I can't argue with that! :)

Comment: @P.E.Dant actually its a bit exaggerated that we wont be able to survive the night because of clammy feet. What we're saying here is that all these factors, the killing cold temp, cutting wind plus the clammy feet (main factor that kept us awake) were the reasons we had a hard time during that moment. And yes, we're using hyperbole.

Comment: @JimReynolds, I agree with Mr P. To my mind, clammy is not something that you cannot feel from inside your body- it's external.  It means that something feels unpleasantly damp when you touch it. The idea of somebody spending the whole night touching their feet and being disturbed by how clammy they feel is somewhat comical.

Comment: @JimReynolds Yes! that's what we're trying to say. thanks man! What can we do to fix the sentence? thanks

Comment: Depending on how bad you want to make it sound, you could replace clammy with **damp**, **wet** or **sodden**. Sodden is in keeping with the spirit of the other adjectives in the sentence. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sodden

Comment: @Jav Whether or not it feels like the best description of what we think the speaker wants to say, *clammy* is sometimes defined and used in the more general sense of, eg, (cold and) damp, which can be sensed of our own bodies, as well as more specifically (cold &) wet *to the touch,* and in any case, we can touch ourselves and feel properties of our own skin.

Comment: @JavaLatte haha that's how we experienced it. We were really disturbed by the feeling. So are you suggesting that sodden or damp is a better adjective to describe the feeling?    eg. Without a ground sheet or even an earth pad, the killing cold temperature and the cutting wind, combined with our sodden feet, made us feel like we wouldn't survive the night.

Comment: @JimReynolds I'm really confused with which adjective could best describe the word.

Comment: I think you need to ask another question, Arkei. This one was about *combined with, along with,* and *coupled with.* I think it's not wrong to say *our clammy feet* there, but I do not know if it's the best word, in part because I don't know exactly how your feet felt! As you can see, some good readers think clammy sounds funny there, or that it may not be correct to write.

Comment: @JimReynolds I know it sounds weird, but if you experience it yourself in the mountain, that's how it really feel. Our feet weren't soaked in water, but because of the weather condition, perhaps the moisture penetrates the tent that probably caused this feeling. Our feet were really clammy.

Answer (score 3):

The writing is grammatical, but not exactly natural for native speakers.

We can use *combined with* as it's used in the text you provided. We can also use *along with* to give the same meaning.

We can also use *coupled with,* but *to couple* means to join two things, or to refer to two things jointly. There are three things mentioned in the text, but we can conceptualize the idea as (A + B) + C.

A more standard way to give the idea expressed is:

> Without a ground sheet or even an earth pad, the killing cold temperature and the cutting wind, combined with our clammy feet, made us feel like we wouldn't survive the night.

The commas I have added shift the meaning to suggest that all three things together made us worry.

Without the commas, it tends more to suggest that these factors acted to link themselves together, or that an external force or agent put them together. This distinction can be a subtle one, or an important one, depending on the context.

*Along with* stands apart from the other choices because it is more likely to suggest that we are referring to things collectively, and does not carry the possible connotation that the things were combined as an action.

Comment: ... is **temperature** really needed? I think not.

Comment: @JavaLatte its really cold that time. freezing cold

Comment: @Arkei, yes, but **killing cold** is enough. You don't need to say **killing cold temperature**. Adding temperature doesn't make it sound colder.. just a bit weird.

Comment: @JavaLatte ooohhhh okay now I get it!